# %TYPE issue in copying datatype in Postgres Functions

Tags: postgresql

When I declare a function in postgres as the following

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "Test_schema".FN_SI_FLOWS ( in_FLOW_ID "Test_schema".FLOWS.FLOW_ID%TYPE)
---
--
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Its throwing me the following error:

> ERROR:  column "flow_id" of relation "flows" does not exist SQL state:
>   42703

Although we have a table called FLOWS in which we have FlOW_ID as column.

Comment: are you sure that your table is in your test_schema? And that your schema name is exctly "Test_schema" (case sensitive)? and your table flows that is this very schema as a column flow_id? (with a 'L' and not a capital 'i')

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the complete `create table` statement for the table `"Test_schema".FLOWS`

Comment: I have verified that the FLOW_ID is given as same as it is in the Function during the creation of table. still it's throwing same error.